# Created scheduled meeting using Zoom API says "Invalid meeting ID. (3,001)" when using different Zoom account for "start_url"

Tags: oauth-2.0, zoom-sdk

Document URL: https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/zoom-api/meetings/meetingcreate

API URL: https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/me/meetings

Request Data: ["type" => 2, "start_time" => "2020-06-30T22:00:00Z"]

I have used Authorization token generated from Account A for the above API request.

I get valid response that includes "start_url" and "join_url".

I am able to join as host if I use the "start_url" logged in with Account A(that's with the account where Authorization token is generated).

But if, I use "start_url" with different account(Account B) it says "Invalid meeting ID. (3,001)".

From the Doc: "start_url" URL to start the meeting. This URL should only be used by the host of the meeting and should not be shared with anyone other than the host of the meeting as anyone with this URL will be able to login to the Zoom Client as the host of the meeting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. The meeting is created in a different timezone, even though I set the same timezone in my API and in my zoom account.

In create a meeting API, I have modified the start time based on the timezone the meeting is created.

NOTE: When logged in as account owner, the scheduled meeting can be started at any time.